# Verifying JTextFields that may not get focus

Tags: java, swing

I've been looking at the java trail on [input verification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html#inputVerification) and I was hoping someone could just confirm that the `InputVerifier` class is the best way to approach my problem.

I've a number of `JTextField`s in a `JPanel`, with a submit button. Each Field is initially blank. The problem is that the Verifier class works on condition of losing focus, but with multiple fields nothing ensures that each gets focus in the first place. For example you could enter a valid entry into the first field, and click submit, despite verification being needed on the following fields.

I'm sure I could rig something together, whereby when the submit button is pressed it checks the relevant `JTextArea`s for any input at all and assigns focus to the first one that still requires data, but I was hoping that there was a more elegant way to check input? Especially as the `InputVerifier` can be set for components rather than just textfields. Tracking or customising focus doesn't really help either as several of the fields are optional but still in a logical order (so I wouldn't want to force focus in an unnatural order just to ensure data entry)

I thought about adding the `InputVerifier` to a containing component, or the submit button, but again, I can't get around the problem of focus.

Comment: I thought that InputVerifier has flexibility when it comes to handling focus. Do you override the `shouldYieldFocus` method of your verifier?

Comment: I read briefly about `shouldYieldFocus`, and also about customising and tracking focus, but no, I haven't yet. I'm double checking it now. but isn't the problem (in my very limited view) not how to yield, but how to make sure that all the components get focus prior to form submission - without enforcing an arbitrary entry order (For example 'name', 'address' and 'postcode' would be required, but I wouldn't want postcode to be answered before the optional field 'city' )

Comment: If this were my code, I'd consider adding the same DocumentListener to all the JTextField Documents. When any change occurs, check all the JTextFields text, validate the data, and if valid, then enable the submission JButton's Action.

Comment: I think you may be right. I've no real knowledge of DocumentListener but have seen it recommended in other questions. I just wanted to double check that InputVerifier might not be the best approach. I assume it's just as easy to then highlight and annotate the incorrect or inappropriate data with a document listener? (I'm sure I'll find out while reading about it either way!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The problem is that the Verifier class works on condition of losing focus, but with multiple fields nothing ensures that each gets focus in the first place. For example you could enter a valid entry into the first field, and click submit, despite verification being needed on the following fields.

That is correct. The InputVerifier only works when the component loses focus.

Typically, there are two types of editing done on a forum:

1. field level edits. These are edits to make sure a component contains valid data. That is numbers are number, postal codes are validated for proper format etc. These type of edits can by done using the InputVerifier
2. form level edits. These ensure that all mandatory fields for the form are entered. This is done when you click the "Submit" button.

If all the fields are mandatory you could try disabling the "Submit" button until data has been entered in all text fields by using logic something like:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;

public class DataEntered implements DocumentListener
{
    private JButton button;
    private List<JTextField> textFields = new ArrayList<JTextField>();

    public DataEntered(JButton button)
    {
        this.button = button;
    }

    public void addTextField(JTextField textField)
    {
        textFields.add( textField );
        textField.getDocument().addDocumentListener( this );
    }

    public boolean isDataEntered()
    {
        for (JTextField textField : textFields)
        {
            if (textField.getText().trim().length() == 0)
                return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e)
    {
        checkData();
    }

    @Override
    public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e)
    {
        checkData();
    }

    @Override
    public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {}

    private void checkData()
    {
        button.setEnabled( isDataEntered() );
    }

    private static void createAndShowUI()
    {
        JButton submit = new JButton( "Submit" );
        submit.setEnabled( false );

        JTextField textField1 = new JTextField(10);
        JTextField textField2 = new JTextField(10);

        DataEntered de = new DataEntered( submit );
        de.addTextField( textField1 );
        de.addTextField( textField2 );

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("SSCCE");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(textField1, BorderLayout.WEST);
        frame.add(textField2, BorderLayout.EAST);
        frame.add(submit, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Just remember using these approach you don't get any message if data is missing.

> I'm sure I could rig something together, whereby when the submit button is pressed it checks the relevant JTextAreas for any input at all and assigns focus to the first one that still requires data, but I was hoping that there was a more elegant way to check input?

This is a perfectly reasonable approach as it give the user visual feedback where the problem is.

Comment: interesting seeing DocumentListener in an example. thanks. i really need to take a detailed look at the class. you mention that you can't notify the end user in this approach, but couldn't I attach individual InputVerifiers to each TextField passed to your class, and then (somehow) use the Verifier to trigger some sort of notification when looping through `isDataEntered()`. I'm sure I haven't thought that through carefully enough, but just thinking outloud :D

Comment: just to try to clarify my probably ill conceived idea: as your `isDataEntered()` loops it could not only check data entry (as shown) but call the `verify()` method of a custom sub-class of InputVerifier that had previously been added to the individual text field? this could allow me to mark which fields needed attention?

Comment: The looping logic is invoked every time a character is entered in any text component. So you don't want to be invoking verifiers every time the user types in the first text field because then haven't even had a chance to enter data in the 2nd, 3rd, etc text fields. Keep it simple separate field level edits from form level edits.

Comment: so every time any field has any data changed it checks **every** field?  i only ask because i've adapted your example to work with my existing form by having it implement DocumentListener and then using `existingTextField.getDocument().addDocumentListener(this)`. `existingTextField2.getDocument().addDocumentListener(this)` etc. other than that I use the same methods but list the existing textfields one by one in `isDataEntered()` rather than looping through an array. i just want to make sure that i haven't accidently made one document listener do way too much work!

Comment: and thanks a lot by the way, i've got it working already - the struggle wasn't as long as when i usually try to implement a new feature!